# Where is my download list ps3

Tags: psn

This may be a stupid question, but, when i claim a game in Ps PLus and go trough the checkup process the games are added to my dowload list, but, where exatly is the download list :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PlayStation then on XMB navigate to `PSN`, then `Account Management`, `Transaction Management`, and there it is `Download List`.

For a web version of list it's [located here](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/download/list). The link is available from a drop-down menu then navigated on your PSN profile name (top right corner).

Answer (score 0):

The list of downloaded games is available from the Playstation store.
Just look through the menu there.
There should be a button on top that says "list of downloaded games" or something similar.

Comment: Is it like a obvious button?